# Retrieve SQL data on dynamic created textbox

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2005, dynamic

I am using C#, Visual Studio 2005

I have created textbox on runtime/dynamic way and inserted/saved sql data on database but the problem is how to retrieve the same data on same way for edit / update.

e.g.

> col1           col2
>
> mahesh         1000
>
> kirti          2000

The above data is stored in sql server. I don't know how to retrieve the same on dynamic way by creating dynamic textbox and retrieve the same.

Suggest proper code please.

Comment: very true sir,

am familiar of it but i want on this way only and this is possible. If u know then please suggest me. am trying on it.

Comment: I have done it. I have bind the Dynamic Textboxes as per Sql Tables.Rows.Count with help of SqlDataAdapter and Dataset. You may bind the textboxes as per sql records./rows

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure i follow 100% but you could have a drop down that is populated from the database, Select the item in this drop down, Enter the details in to your textboxes and have a button to activate the update.

In steps
Get your data into a local list.
Populate the drop down using this list.

You now still have your local list with the appropriate data.

Get the user to select an item from the drop down.
Use the drop downs selected index to get the item from the list.
Change the values within this item and commit to the database

I would have thought it would be far easier using the appropriate control for displaying the information such as a listview or datagrid

```
   List<String> objInformationList = new List<String>();
objInformationList = "Your database query function";
foreach(String objCurrentString in objInformationList){
// Create your text box
// Set your text within your textbox
// Add the text box to the screen or a table structure
}
```

I personally would be doing this another way

Comment: am appreciate ur reply.

but it's time consuming. See user enter data on specific dynamically created textboxes and saved it. and as per ur suggestion again populate data on drop down and modifying it's not well sir, i have to directly populate data on textbox which is save the time. suppose i have three sql records so textbox will be three there by binding the data. "time is Precious Sir"

Comment: So if the database contains 3 cols lets say col 1, col 2, col 3(col 1 is your unique identifier). You then have 2 textboxes(which accept values for col 2 and col 3 as col 1 is an autoincrement) dynamically created which accept values and when you click a button they get sent to the database What you want to do now is use the dynamically created textboxes to update the data within the database?

Comment: no sir,

suppose I have col1 in sql database in which three records available for specific ID i want to bind this three records or rows in three textboxes dynamically/runtime. In future it may be more than three so how is do please provide necessary code.

Comment: thx sir,

am trying ur above suggested code and will get u later. if u done this by another way then please suggest me.

Comment: i wouldn't be putting the data in to textboxes for display i would be using a listview or a gridview a control that was created to display information

Comment: as above said 
objectinformationList = " Your database query function".

so u mean to provide "select sql query" which is raise system error cannot convert type string or further. please clear

Comment: Finally I have done it by the Sql Tables.Rows.Count with help of SqlDataAdapter and Dataset. I have bind whatever records or rows availabe in Sql tables with Dynamic Textboxes. 

thx for ur Help.

Answer (score 0):

Create datasource. Read the data into the datasource. Add the controls and bind the dynamic controls to that data source.